# An internal error occurred during: "Launching <myApp>". Java heap space

Tags: java, android, eclipse, heap-memory

When I run my Android app in Eclipse Juno it shows:

> An internal error occurred during: "Launching ". Java heap space".

I have modified my `eclipse.ini` file  with

```
Xms:1024m
Xmx:1024m
```

Unfortunately this did not solve the problem.

Comment: you have to set those jvm parameters in the launch configuration for you app, not in the eclipse.ini file

Comment: Does it leave its stack trace in your Logcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that `OutOfMemoryError` occurs not in Eclipse, but in the spawned JVM where your application works. You should modify parameters in your run configuration. Go to Run -> Run Configurations, find your application run configuration in the left pane and select it. On the right pane select "Arguments" tab, there should be "VM arguments" test field. Add there `-Xmx1024m`.

Comment: how to set default vm arguments for all java application run configurations (i dont want to change it every time)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know. I set them separately for each run configuration. Probably it's impossible, but maybe I'm wrong. You may try to ask a new question.